# docker-compose simple example with nginx php and mysql

Tags: docker-compose

Can someone help me to connect my PHP and MySQL
I did manage to make it up and running, connect to DB with MySQL Workbench but when I try PDO connect from PHP file it fails for some reason...

docker-compose

```
web:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
        - "80:80"
    volumes:
        - ./:/var/www
        - ./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf
    links:
        - php
php:
    image: php:7-fpm
    volumes:
        - ./:/var/www
    links:
        - db

db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
     - /var/lib/mysql
    environment:
     - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456
     - MYSQL_DATABASE=database
    ports:
     - "3306:3306"
```

site.conf

```
server {
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name lara.test;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

and index.php

```
<?php

$database = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database', "root", "123456");
echo "Connected to MySQL<br />";

?>
```

and error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver in
>   /var/www/index.php:3 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/index.php(3):
>   PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', '123456') #1 {main}
>   thrown in /var/www/index.php on line 3

what do I miss in order to make this work?

Comment: Dude, the PHP image is bare. The error is self explanatory, the MySQL drivers are missing. Create custom image or use another.

Comment: I tried put dockerfile with RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli && \
  docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql, but no luck

Comment: No wonder, I’m going to sleep already. Hit me tomorrow should you still need help with this.

Answer (score 1):

Just change

> $database = new PDO('mysql:host=**localhost**;dbname=database', "root",
>   "123456");

to

> $database = new PDO('mysql:host=**db**;dbname=database', "root", "123456");

the name of `host` must same with the name of database image on `docker-compose` file.